# How to call a method expressed as a string

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def show_block_path
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.gate_path(resource_id))
end
```

I'm trying have to refactor it:

```
def show_block_path
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers."{resource_type.downcase}"_path(resource_id))
end
```

`resource_type.downcase` is `"gate"`, but the method doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Basically because `foo.bar` != `foo."bar"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
def show_block_path
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.public_send(
    "#{resource_type.downcase}_path", resource_id
  )
end
```